# Как получить пользователей с помощью LDAP в 1С?

Tags: 1с, ldap

Я хочу в 1C достать всех пользователей с помощью LDAPS из Active Directory.

Когда я использую `ПолучитьCOMОбъект("LDAP://domain.ru:123")`, то возвращается COM объект. Но это с LDAP, а надо LDAPS. И в отладчике еще почему-то COM объект пустой. Но если написать `ПолучитьCOMОбъект("LDAPS://domain.ru:123")`, то почему-то сразу ошибка вылетает.

Не понятно почему не работает, потому что есть еще отдельный почтовый сервис (не в 1С), который тоже использует LDAPS, и там все нормально работает.

Еще просто сделать `ПолучитьCOMОбъект("LDAPS://domain.ru:123")` тоже нельзя, потому что нужно авторизоваться. Видел в примерах, что авторизуются с помощью `логин@домен`, но нашел еще вариант с `CN=admins,CN=login` или `UID=login,CN=admins,CN=login`.

Пробовал авторизироваться способами ниже, которые в итоге тоже не сработали из-за ошибки `Произошла исключительная ситуация (Active Directory): The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.`.

```
COMОбъект = ПолучитьCOMОбъект("LDAP://");
Корень = COMОбъект.OpenDSObject("LDAP://RootDSE", "login@domain.ru:123", "password", 1);
```

```
COMОбъект = ПолучитьCOMОбъект("LDAP://domain.ru:123");
Корень = COMОбъект.OpenDSObject("LDAP://OU=people,DC=domain,DC=ru", "CN=admins,CN=login", "password", 1);
```

**UPD1:**
Сейчас еще пробую подключится так:

```
СоединениеАДО = Новый COMОбъект("ADODB.Connection");
        СоединениеАДО.ConnectionString = "Provider=ADSDSOObject;User Id=login;Password=password;"; 
        СоединениеАДО.Open();
```

Но в третьей строке возникает ошибка

```
Произошла исключительная ситуация (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers): [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

**UPD2:**
Сейчас максимально далеко зашел:

```
СоединениеАДО = Новый COMОбъект("ADODB.Connection");
СоединениеАДО.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"; 
СоединениеАДО.Properties("User Id").Value = "login";
СоединениеАДО.Properties("Password").Value = "password";
СоединениеАДО.Open("LDAPS://domain.ru:636");
```

В 3 и 4 строке всё работает, но не работает вторая (5 пока не могу проверить без 2). Во второй строке появляется ошибка `(ADODB.Connection): Supplied provider is different from the one already in use.`. По умолчанию стоит `MSDASQL.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Может поможет [эта публикация](https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/1171021/)? Почитайте комментарии.

Comment: Да, тут смотрел. Пробовал сделать у себя так: `ДСО = ПолучитьCOMОбъект("LDAP:");    Корень = ДСО.OpenDSObject("LDAP://ex.name.ru:123", "login@ex.name.ru", "password",1);`, но тоже не работает. Появляется ошибка `Произошла исключительная ситуация (Active Directory): A device attached to the system is not functioning.` во второй строке с корнем

Comment: Процедура с этим кодом в общих модулях. Может ли быть проблема в этом?

Comment: @shitslark, попробуй почитать (https://yandex.ru/search/?text=Active+Directory%3A+A+device+attached+to+the+system+is+not+functioning&lr=11&clid=2207714) думаю тут что-то настроне AD или Windows

Answer (score 0):

Вот работающий пример; Попробуй сделать таким же образом.

```
dso = ПолучитьCOMОбъект("LDAP:");
        
        Попытка
            Объект_AD = dso.OpenDSObject("LDAP://"+Настройки.Домен+Порт+"/"+КонтейнерОбъекта, Настройки.Пользователь,Настройки.ПарольРасшифрованный, ?(ИспользоватьSSL,2,1));               
        Исключение
            Объект_AD = Null;               
        КонецПопытки;
```

Comment: Появляется ошибка `Произошла исключительная ситуация (Active Directory): A device attached to the system is not functioning.`. Пробовал так сделать: `Объект_AD = ДСО.OpenDSObject("LDAP://ex.name.ru:123/OU=people/DC=name/DC=ru", "login@ex.name.ru", "password", 1);` В последний параметр пробовал `2` и `1` передавать

Comment: Это уже с настройками AD проблема; см: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/53022/a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-functioning   сразу читай {Accepted answer} P.S. по AD не специалист

Comment: Нет, всё нормально. Там есть Users

Comment: Получилось что-то получить с помощью `Корень = ПолучитьCOMОбъект("LDAP:");
        Объект_AD = Корень.OpenDSObject("LDAP://домен:порт", "логин", "пароль", 2);`. Но что нужно сделать дальше, чтобы получить пользователей из OU=people?

Comment: ADOСоединение = МодульActiveDirectoryОбщий.ПолучитьСоединение(Настройки.Пользователь, Настройки.Пароль);
 ADOКоманда = МодульActiveDirectoryОбщий.СоздатьОбъектADOКоманда(ADOСоединение, ОграничениеРазмераБлокаДанных);
 СписокОбъектов = МодульActiveDirectoryОбщий.ОтправитьЗапрос(ADOКоманда, ТекстЗапроса, ИмяПоляДляСортировки);

Comment: А что за МодульActiveDirectoryОбщий?

Comment: Это у меня есть конфа с таким модулем; Вам следует посмотреть примеры в интернете по ADO Command; https://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_command.asp