# Как изменить провайдер COM объекта в 1С?

Tags: 1с, ldap

Я хочу получить пользователей в 1С с помощью LDAPS. Для этого нужно сначала создать подключение:

```
ADOConnection = Новый COMОбъект("ADODB.Connection");
ADOConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject";
```

Но почему-то во второй строке появляется ошибка и заменить провайдер не получается (по умолчанию стоит MSDASQL.1).

Если не менять провайдер и просто выполнить код:

```
ADOConnection = Новый COMОбъект("ADODB.Connection"); 
ADOConnection.Properties("User Id").Value = "login";
ADOConnection.Properties("Password").Value = "password";
ADOConnection.Open();
```

То на 4 строке будет ошибка:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Погуглил, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115632/microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-drive) пишут, что нужно добавить провайдер в список. Но у меня нет провайдера ADsDSOObject.

[image]

Как его можно добавить в этот список. И точно ли нужен ADsDSOObject для LDAPS? На сервере уже установлен OpenLDAP, может его можно как провайдер как-то добавить?

Comment: Не занаю, что такое LDAPS, но у меня все параметры подключения к драйверу MySql устанавливаются через ConnectionString =
"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};"+
"SERVER=xxx;"+
"DATABASE=xxx;"+
"UID=xxx;"+
"PWD=xxx;"+
"MULTI_STATEMENTS=1;"+
"MULTI_RESULTS=1;"+
"STMT=SET CHARACTER SET utf8";

Answer (score 1):

Зачем его менять то ??? В ошибке же написано "*Data source name not found*" На вкладке *User DSN* Создайте источник данных, в коде используйте его имя для подключения.

P.S. Что означает *хочу получить пользователей 1С ?* (причем тут LDAP ?! надеюсь Вы знаете что делаете)

Comment: На вкладке User DSN уже есть Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb). Если его попробовать указать в ADOConnection.Provider, то пишет: `(ADODB.Connection): Supplied provider is different from the one already in use.`. Если вы имели в виду создать в User DSN какой-нибудь драйвер с лдапом, то пока не могу понять как это сделать, потому что там доступны для создания те же драйверы, которые на скриншоте.
_Мне нужно получить пользователей из AD с помощью LDAP'а с шифрованием (LDAPS)._

Comment: Так уже разобрались же ?! Тот способ не работает ?!  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1496775/Как-получить-пользователей-с-помощью-ldap-в-1С

Comment: Еще вариант - либо укажите провайдера из вкладки User DSN, либо создайте свой DSN и укажите нужного провайдера;